# Detecting Bluetooth Device Sleep State Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am working on an application which has Bluetooth connection as core part. Currently the app is connecting to and communicating with the Bluetooth device successfully. The main problem now is that the device we are using to collect data goes into sleep mode after some idle condition.

My question is, how can I detect that the device is in sleep mode so that my application can ask the user to wake up the device?

I am connecting through SSP. Connection code is exact copy of Bluetooth Chat application from API demo.

**Sleep Mode** -- The device (Not Mobile) to which my application is connected runs on a battery, so optimize use of battery if Android application don't any request to the device in 1 min Device goes in sleep mode.(May be off without dropping connection). So my application need to catch this condition and let the user know that device is in sleep mode and wake it up so it can respond to applications request.
This is the best way I can explain sleep mode. Keep in mind sleep mode of Bluetooth device and not the android mobile.

Comment: What do you mean by sleep mode can you explain the scenario

Comment: @ricintech  Please check question again added information on sleep mode...

Comment: If you are using Bluetooth socket connection then it won't be disconnected after 1 min please check you are not making the socket null in onDestroy() method of your activity.

Comment: Could you paste few lines of code for making Bluetooth connection request.

Comment: @ricintech -- 1) My activity is working properly. 2)Issue is detecting remote device sleep state. 3) For code not a single line of change in bluetooth chat application code...

Comment: As you told me that you are using SSP connection so could you paste the UUID which you are using because Bluetooth chat is not using SSP.

Comment: private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution --- 
I know it's not perfect but still I m working on it...
Whenever connection drops I get socket error which I use as the remote device is in sleep mode or out of reach or dead. Also I changed my code so that I doesn't require UUID(Now it's low level connection) Code as below.

```
public class HHDBapiBTService {
// Debugging
private static final String TAG = "HHDBapiBTService";
private static final boolean D = true;

private BluetoothSocket mmSocket = null;
private InputStream mmInStream = null;
private OutputStream mmOutStream = null;

// Member fields
private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
private Handler mHandler;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private int mState;


// Constants that indicate the current connection state
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0; // we're doing nothing
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1; // now listening for incoming
                                            // connections
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing
                                                // connection
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3; // now connected to a remote
                                                // device

public static final int STATE_SLEEP = 4; // now connected to a remote
// device


/**
 * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            The UI Activity Context
 * @param handler
 *            A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
 */
public HHDBapiBTService(Context context, Handler handler) {
    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    mHandler = handler;
}

/**
 * Set the current state of the chat connection
 * 
 * @param state
 *            An integer defining the current connection state
 */
public synchronized void setState(int state) {
    if (D)
        Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
    mState = state;

    // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
    mHandler.obtainMessage(GlobalValues.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1)
            .sendToTarget();
}

/**
 * Return the current connection state.
 */
public synchronized int getState() {
    return mState;
}

public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
    mHandler = handler;
}

/**
 * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
 * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
 */
public synchronized void start() {
    if (D)
        Log.d(TAG, "start");

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    setState(STATE_LISTEN);
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
 * 
 * @param device
 *            The BluetoothDevice to connect
 */
public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (D)
        Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
 * 
 * @param socket
 *            The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
 * @param device
 *            The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
 */
public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket,
        BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (D)
        Log.d(TAG, "connected");

    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}

/**
 * Stop all threads
 */
public synchronized void stop() {
    if (D)
        Log.d(TAG, "stop");
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel(true);
        mConnectThread = null;
    }
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    setState(STATE_NONE);
}

/**
 * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
 * 
 * @param out
 *            The bytes to write
 * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
 */
public void write(byte[] out) {
    if(getState() == STATE_SLEEP){
        connectionLost();
        return;
    }
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED)
            return;
        r = mConnectedThread;

    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}

public void closeConnection(){
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED)
            return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    r.cancel();
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionFailed() {
    if(getState() != STATE_LISTEN){
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(GlobalValues.MESSAGE_SHOW_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(GlobalValues.TOAST, "HHD device is in sleep mode or out-of range. Please shake the HHD device to make it active.");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionLost() {
    //setState(STATE_LISTEN);

    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    /*Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(GlobalValues.MESSAGE_SHOW_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(GlobalValues.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);*/
    setState(STATE_SLEEP);
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(
                         GlobalValues.MESSAGE_REMOTE_DEVICE_LOST);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}


/**
 * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection with a
 * device. It runs straight through; the connection either succeeds or
 * fails.
 */
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected boolean simpleComm(Integer port) {
        // byte [] inputBytes = null;

        // The documents tell us to cancel the discovery process.
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        Log.d(this.toString(), "Port = " + port);
        try {
            Method m = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
                    new Class[] { int.class });
            mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mmDevice, port);

            // debug check to ensure socket was set.
            assert (mmSocket != null) : "Socket is Null";

            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            // attempt to connect to device
            mmSocket.connect();
            try {
                Log.d(this.toString(),
                        "************ CONNECTION SUCCEES! *************");

                // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
                /*synchronized (HHDBapiBTService.this) {
                    mConnectThread = null;
                }*/

                connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
                return true;
            } finally {
                // close the socket and we are done.
                // //mmSocket.close();
            }
            // IOExcecption is thrown if connect fails.
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(this.toString(), "IOException " + ex.getMessage());
            if (port == 256) {
                connectionFailed();
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                    mmSocket = null;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            Log.e(this.toString(),
                    "NoSuchMethodException " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Log.e(this.toString(),
                    "IllegalAccessException " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
            Log.e(this.toString(),
                    "InvocationTargetException " + ex.getMessage());
        }catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            Log.e(this.toString(),
                    "NullPointerException " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (Integer port = 1; port <= 256; port++) {
            if (simpleComm(Integer.valueOf(port)))
                break;
        }

    }

    public void cancel() {
         /*if (mmSocket != null) { 
             try { 
                 mmSocket.close(); mmSocket = null;
             } catch (IOException e) { 
                 Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect secure socket failed", e); 
             } 
         }*/
    }

    public void cancel(boolean val) {
         if (mmSocket != null) { 
             try { 
                 mmSocket.close(); mmSocket = null;
             } catch (IOException e) { 
                 Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect secure socket failed", e); 
             } 
         }
    }

}

/**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device. It handles all
 * incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    private Logger logger;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        logger = Logger.getInstance();

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;
        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        //Logic to parse the Inputstream
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    HHDBapiBTService.this.stop();
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    //connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     * 
     * @param buffer
     *            The bytes to write
     */

    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionLost();
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }

}
}
```